# How to add search feature before loading app

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js, ionic-framework

We are developing for youtube channel using Ionic and AngularJS. search feature is working only after loading videos through api. How to give a condition where search box is empty then videos have to load automatically. If there is anything in search box it have to search all the channel for that particular videos containing title and description matching with search box.

```
(function() {

  //Make it expressive by introducing new variable app. App now in global space (bad practics)
  var app = angular.module('youtubevideo', ['ionic', 'youtube-embed', 'ngCordova', 'ngIOS9UIWebViewPatch']);

  app.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
      if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
        cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      }
      if(window.StatusBar) {
        StatusBar.styleDefault();
      }
    });
  });

  //**** Version 2: Refactory codes to use pull to refresh, and infinite scroll ***//
 app.controller('mycontroller', function($scope, $http, $ionicModal){

   $scope.videos = [];    
   $scope.appname = "";

   $scope.playerVars = {
       rel: 0,
       showinfo: 0,
       modestbranding: 0,
     }

   $scope.nextPageToken = null;

   $scope.youtubeParams = {
     key: 'my_secretkey',
     type: 'video',
     maxResults: '50',
     part: 'id,snippet',
     q: 'iphone',
     order: 'videoCount',
     channelId: 'my_secretchannelid'    
   }

   function loadVideos(params, callback) {
       $http.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search', {params: params}).success(function(response){            
         var videos = [];
         if(response.nextPageToken) {
           $scope.nextPageToken = response.nextPageToken;
           console.log ($scope.nextPageToken);
           console.log(response.items);
           angular.forEach(response.items, function(child){
             videos.push(child);
           });
         }

         callback(videos);            
       });
     }

   $scope.loadOlderVideos = function() {
     var params = $scope.youtubeParams; 
     if ($scope.nextPageToken) {
       params['pageToken'] = $scope.nextPageToken;
     }
     loadVideos(params, function(olderVideos){
       if (olderVideos) {
         $scope.videos = $scope.videos.concat(olderVideos);
       }
       $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');
     });
   };

   $scope.loadNewerVideos = function() {
     var params = $scope.youtubeParams;
     params['pageToken'] = '';
       loadVideos(params, function(newerVideos) {
         $scope.videos = newerVideos;
         $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
       });    
     };    
  });    
}());
```

Comment: You should not put sensitive things like keys, IDs or Credentials with the code.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use videos api when there is no search content.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos
```